# How to get years and months with momentjs and vuejs

Tags: vue.js, momentjs, vuetify.js

I'm trying to display relative time with momentjs in the format:

> years and months i.e. 2 years and 8 months

Currently, `2016-01-29 | moment('from', 'now', true)` just rounds up to 3 years.

The [vue-moment package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment) has no direct way of doing this, [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) as well does not appear to handle this either

I'm trying not to use any extra plugin as well.

Comment: sorry, you won't be able to do it using momentjs. You will need to handle the conversion yourself. Count the months, and get the modulo `x%12` to gen months and `Math.floor(x/12)` to get years. Then add it into a directive or plugin to make accessible.

Comment: @Daniel thanks the response. I had imagine I'll have to do this, but thought there was a direct implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break the moment calculation down into milliseconds.

```
let fromTime = moment("2016-01-29").diff(moment(), "milliseconds")
```

Then create a duration object using the diff provided.

```
let duration = moment.duration(fromTime)
```

It will return a duration object that will have methods for milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours, days, months and years.

The `duration.methods()` methods return negative values, thats why there is a divide by negative one `/ -1` to convert the values into positive ones.

Here is an example using the `duration.years()` and `duration.months()`

```
let timeString = duration.years() / -1 + " years and " + duration.months() / -1 + " months"
```

So as of right now the `timeString` would return `2 years and 6 months`.

Comment: Would try this as well

Comment: This worked as expected! with little tweaks which I added as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 2):

// import moment

```
var moment = require('moment')
```

// add this as a method in your component

```
 getYearsMonthsDays(date){
        let fromTime = moment(date).diff(moment(), "milliseconds")
        let duration = moment.duration(fromTime)
        let years = duration.years() / -1
        let months = duration.months() / -1
        let days = duration.days() / -1
        if (years > 0) {
            var Ys = years == 1? years + " year and ": years + " years and "
            var Ms = months == 1? months + " month": months + " months"
            return Ys + Ms
        } else {
            if (months > 0)
                return months == 1? months + " month": months + " months"
            else
                return days == 1? days + " day": days + " days"
        }
    }
```

// usage in component

```
{{ getYearsMonthsDays(date) }}
```

This works as expected with tweaks from @jordanw 's response.
May be it could be made shorter or better but this works ok.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that uses date-fns ans creates a custom filter

https://codesandbox.io/s/mmm0q9r61x

this is the code for the filter itself

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { differenceInMonths, differenceInYears } from "date-fns";

Vue.filter("tsDiff", (from, to) => {
  const tsTo = to || new Date();
  try {
    // return `${distanceInWords(from, tsTo)}`;
    let y = differenceInYears(from, tsTo);
    let m = differenceInMonths(from, tsTo) - y * 12;
    let r = [];
    if (y !== 0) {
      r.push(`${Math.abs(y)} Year${Math.abs(y) !== 1 ? "s" : ""}`);
    }
    if (m !== 0) {
      r.push(`${Math.abs(m)} Month${Math.abs(m) !== 1 ? "s" : ""}`);
    }
    r = r.join(" and ");
    if (y < 0 || m < 0) {
      r = r + " ago";
    } else {
      r = "In " + r;
    }
    return r;
  } catch (error) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    console.error(error);
    return "Invalid Date";
  }
});
```

once you import the filter (`import './datefilter';`), you can call from anywhere as `{{ myDate | tsDiff }}`

you can adjust the use as needed.

You can easily replace the use of `differenceInYears` and `differenceInMonths` with vanilla js so that you don't need a dependency at all.

As a side note, have a look if you can replace momentjs with date-fns. Momentjs is a nice library, but you have to load the entire library no matter how much you are using. When you use Date-fns however, you can specify which parts you want to use, and only those get injected into the final build. This can save a lot on the final build size.

Comment: Thanks. This may work, but as I stated not trying to use any other library just momentjs

Comment: you can use moment js with small changes. Replacing `differenceInYears` with `moment().diff(from, 'years');` and similarly with the `differenceInMonths`